# Positioning a coloured background rectangle using the background package

Tags: positioning, backgrounds, coordinates

I am trying to get a background rectangle of colour covering one of two columns on a page done with multicol, with the rectangle going right to the edge of the paper.

I am confused about the position= option to the \backgroundsetup command of the background package, as it doesn't appear to bear any relationship to the bottom corner of the page. In the example below, I try to adjust the width of the rectangle to take the margins into account. The vertical position seems to be half-way up the page, despite the y-position being zero. I am clearly misunderstanding something here, but I can't see what.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol,calc}
\usepackage[a4paper,twoside,
  textheight=240mm,footskip=25mm,
  inner=20mm,outer=35mm,top=15mm, nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\setlength{\columnsep}{10mm}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \raggedright
  \parskip=\baselineskip
  \parindent=0pt}
\newlength{\bgwidth}% calculated width of rectangle
\newlength{\bgxpos}% calculated location of x-position
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leftcolbackground}{% try to make it work L and R
  \ifodd\c@page
    \setlength{\bgxpos}{20mm}%
    \setlength{\bgwidth}{\bgxpos + \oddsidemargin}%
  \else
    \setlength{\bgxpos}{35mm}%
    \setlength{\bgwidth}{\bgxpos + \evensidemargin}%
  \fi
  \addtolength{\bgwidth}{\columnwidth}% assumes we are inside multicols
  \typeout{columnwidth=\the\columnwidth, bgxpos=\the\bgxpos,
    bgwidth=\the\bgwidth}% 
  \def\colbg{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[yellow] (0,0) rectangle (\bgwidth,\paperheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
  \backgroundsetup{scale=1,color=black,opacity=1,
    angle=0,position={\bgxpos,0},contents=\colbg}
  \BgThispage}
\makeatother
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[5]
\lipsum[6]
\lipsum[7]
\lipsum[8]
\lipsum[9]
\lipsum[10]
\leftcolbackground
\section{This is a demo}
\lipsum[11]
\lipsum[12]
\subsection{Increasing the uptake of STEM candidates}
\lipsum[13]
\lipsum[14]
\section{This is another demo}
\lipsum[15]
\lipsum[16]
\lipsum[17]
\lipsum[18]
\subsection{More subtitling}
\lipsum[19]
\lipsum[20]
\lipsum[21]
\lipsum[22]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: Colour rectangle not positioned as expected]

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to start with

```
\backgroundsetup{scale=1,color=black,opacity=1,contents=\colbg,
  angle=0,position=current page.south,nodeanchor=south east}
```

or

```
\backgroundsetup{scale=1,color=black,opacity=1,contents=\colbg,
  angle=0,position=current page.south,nodeanchor=south west}
```

to get the rectangle into defined position and then shift it with `hshift=...` or `vshift=...`, like in

```
\backgroundsetup{scale=1,color=black,opacity=1,contents=\colbg,
  angle=0,position=current page.south,nodeanchor=south east,hshift=1in}
```

Here is the output of these three settings.

> [image]  [image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Using overlays you can position a `tikzpicture` relative to the page:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol,calc}
\usepackage[a4paper,twoside,
  textheight=240mm,footskip=25mm,
  inner=20mm,outer=35mm,top=15mm, nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\setlength{\columnsep}{10mm}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \raggedright
  \parskip=\baselineskip
  \parindent=0pt}
\newlength{\bgwidth}% calculated width of rectangle
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leftcolbackground}{%
  \setlength{\bgwidth}{\dimexpr\marginparwidth+.5\marginparsep+.5\textwidth}
  \ifodd\c@page
    \addtolength{\bgwidth}{\oddsidemargin}
  \else
    \addtolength{\bgwidth}{\evensidemargin}
  \fi
  \def\colbg{%
    \tikz[overlay]{
      \fill[yellow] (current page.north west) ++(\bgwidth,0) rectangle (current page.south west);
    }
  }
  \backgroundsetup{scale=1,opacity=1,angle=0,contents=\colbg}
  \BgThispage
  }
\makeatother
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\leftcolbackground
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[5]
\lipsum[6]
\lipsum[7]
\lipsum[8]
\lipsum[9]
\lipsum[10]
\leftcolbackground
\section{This is a demo}
\lipsum[11]
\lipsum[12]
\subsection{Increasing the uptake of STEM candidates}
\lipsum[13]
\lipsum[14]
\section{This is another demo}
\lipsum[15]
\lipsum[16]
\lipsum[17]
\lipsum[18]
\subsection{More subtitling}
\lipsum[19]
\lipsum[20]
\lipsum[21]
\lipsum[22]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: odd page][image: even page]

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm still baffled by two things, though: (a) what is the reference point for the coordinates used in \backgroundsetup's position option; and (b) against what reference point of the content does it apply them? That is, I can see that (0,0) refers to TikZ's (0,0), but which bit of the content does it put there — clearly not the bottom LH corner!

Comment: Part of the confusion is the otherwise excellent PGF manual (p.38) where it says: "You can add a single + sign in front of a coordinate or two of them as in +(1cm,0cm) or ++(0cm,2cm). Such coordinates are interpreted differently: The first form means '1cm upwards from the previous specified
position' and the second means '2cm to the right of the previous specified position, [...]'". Surely this is wrong: the first means 1cm to the right, and the second means 2cm up? Or are the coordinates in adjustments really reversed (y,x)?

Comment: It looks to me as though `\backgroundsetup`'s (0,0) is 1 inch below and 1 inch to the right of the top left corner of the page, and by default it centers the content there (`nodeanchor=center`). But in most cases it is probably best to position relative to the `current page` node instead of worrying about this strange  coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks...one final query: if I try to parameterise the second argument to the ++(\bgwidth,#1) to move the background down the page (using a value passed from an argument to the \leftcolbackground command), it works perfectly the first time, but when I use the command a second time on a later page, it repeats the positioning of the first usage, ignoring the new value of the argument. Is there a way to make the \tikz command forget what it has done once it's been used?

Comment: I'm having trouble replicating your issue. If I change the code above to `\newcommand{\leftcolbackground}[1]{`...`++(\bgwidth,-#1)`, repeated uses of `\leftcolbackground` observe the argument as expected. Of course, if it is called multiple times on the _same_ page then only the last call counts.

Comment: Hmm. Nor can I, when I just modify the code above to add the optional argument [1][0] to \leftcolbackground, and use -#1 as you indicated. In my much larger and more complex dev code, any second and subsequent uses on later pages always show the same offset as the first use (I used 8cm as the value on the first call, so that the background started where the text of the chapter starts). I'll need to investigate this more. It's made more complex by the fact that TikZ appears to record each instance in the .aux file, which is why I think it's becoming mixed up over which one to re-use.